# Why iOS Sticker app warning on iOS 13 with 32 bit architecture? TMS-90747

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, ios-stickers

TMS-90747: Architecture incompatible with MinimumOSVersion. The app bundle at 'Blankbook.app/PlugIns/BlankbookSticker.appex' specifies a MinimumOSVersion of '13.0' but contains a 32-bit architecture that is unsupported on iOS 12 and later.

I received the above warning when trying to add a sticker extension to the existing app that targeted 13.0

I did nothing fancy but added the required stickers to the pack. I'm wondering if its some setting I'm missing something that triggers the warning above when try to upload to App Store?

Answer (score 2):

Ok.... seems you have to set sticker extension target below iOS 11 for now to erase the warning.

Comment: That is not a good solution!? I have an all SwiftUI which requires iOS 14+ which also has stickers... so lowering the target below iOS 14 is not an option for me!?

Comment: You can lower Deployment target just for the Stickers target. All others targets (including main app) can be higher.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me but setting the target to iOS 10 cleared that warning for me. Also had to uncheck the "Apple Silicon Mac Availability — Make this app available" box (App Store Connect, Pricing and Availability) because I was getting two errors that didn't appear to be linked but always showed up together.